# What is the proper way to pass config/parameters to class library?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, config, app-config

I'm creating a class library that is meant to be used by a lot of different clients. I want it to be configureable, for example I want to be able to specify the path for temporary files of the library in the client.

I'm wondering what is the 'correct' way to do that? Is there a way to read(inherit) client's appconfig from class library? Should it be passed by dependency injection? The easiest solution would be to pass it by parameter, but then my library would have to pass it around or store in a static variable, but it's not a very clean solution...

Comment: The proper way is `config` file.

Comment: DI via interface is my vote

Comment: It totally depends on you and what your library does. Think about any logger service. Most of the logger are configurable either by the property in config file or we can set parameters. 

IMHO The use of libraries are often based easily it can be configured for the basic task.

Comment: I would be very careful about using a config file in dlls, becaise it makes it harder to use - every application that uses this dll must be aware of the specific configuration needed. You better expose an API for setting the configurable parts (be it using constructor / method parameters, or using properties, or even using a MyDllConfig struct), and leave the calling applications to decide what to put in the configuration file and what to do hard coded.

Comment: @Zohar Peled But where would you store those settings configured by API? Serialize them and save to file, store as static parameters..?

Comment: It all depends on your specific needs. If your dll contains a static class that needs the configuration, then static variables inside that class or perhaps pass them as parameters to the methods of that class. If it contains non-static classes then perhaps you should pass them in the constructor and store them in fields... There is no "one size fits all" for this.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to read(inherit) client's appconfig from class library?

If you use the normal method of reading Configuration from .config or appsettings in your library, it will automatically take the .config or appsettings file for the application it is used in.

Please be advised that this will make it less transparent to use the library, since it needs specific configuration items to work (properly). I would make sure it has default values for all settings you might want to put in configuration.